# Cannot Highlight as default ListView items based on ArrayAdapter and ViewHolder in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and I want to get my saved selections from SQLite and display them as highlighted options in order for the user to update his selections.

So far I get my values in a List, I get their corresponding position in listview by using:

```
int ItemPos = mAdapter.getPosition(Alist.get(i).toString());
mAdapter.toggleSelection(ItemPos);
```

and my adapter is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));

    return view;
}


public void toggleSelection(int position){
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value) {
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        holder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FJFJFJ"));
    }
    else{
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I run this I get that

```
Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView.AnswerListAdapter$ViewHolder.itemName' on a null object reference
```

**How to change the color of my items ?**

Thank you

Comment: How you are able to access holder.itemName  in selectView. It think this getting you error

Comment: how I am going to access the item to change its color? if not with view holder?

Comment: adding answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in adapter pass data array of boolean and set its value in activity in place of following two lines

```
int ItemPos = mAdapter.getPosition(Alist.get(i).toString());
mAdapter.toggleSelection(ItemPos);
```

Modify getView as below

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

if(data.get(position))
holder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FJFJFJ"));
else
holder.itemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("set normal color other wise you will face problem on scrolling"));

    holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));

    return view;
}
```